# Cannot trigger event ngModelChange when doing clone deep of value

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying without success to to calculate the sum of a row values. I think it's because I do a deep cloning of the row values array when I create the row.

```
      const gblRowVal1 = new GridRowValues(1, this.color, this.headList.map(x => Object.assign(new RefQuantities(), x )), this.availableColors)
```

The ngModel is not pointing to the colomn value, so the ngModelChange is not triggered, therefore the total is not calculated

```
(ngModelChange)="onRowClick($event, row, headItem)"
```

[Plunker grid](https://plnkr.co/edit/fWacDPTBT1npKkXaeGS2?p=preview)

Comment: Are you open to suggestion of adding new property in your class (and object) for the total amount?

Comment: hello again @AJT_82, yes I tried adding the total as an attribute of GridRowValues, but the issue is the ngModelChange that is not triggered when I modify the input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would suggest is the easiest way, is to add a new property to your class model, let's say `total`. When that property is in place for your `GridRowValues` class it is quite easy to incorporate the total amount.

You can add a change event, in this case use `(ngModelChange)` with the actual `ngModel`, i.e `headItem.value` instead of `headItem.value[childIndex]` and in that pass the current row:

```html
<td *ngFor='#headItem of row.headList; #childIndex = index'>
  <input [(ngModel)]="headItem.value" 
         (ngModelChange)="onRowClick(row)" 
         type="number">
<td>
```

and in that change event you can count the total and assign it to the new property `row.total`:

```ts
onRowClick(row) {
  let total = 0;
  row.headList.forEach(x => {
    if(x.value) {
      total += x.value;
    }
  })
  row.total = total;
}
```

and just display it like any other `ngModel`:

```html
<input readonly="readonly" [(ngModel)]="row.total" type="number">
```

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/Hm8Xa0WMSHGYwLtsvEig?p=preview)**

Comment: works like a sharm, tkx @AJT_82. What I was missing I guess is passing the index the headItem value, somehow it wasn't triggering the on model change.

Comment: Glad to hear it worked! To mention, the ngModelChange **is** fired, but since the ngModel points to something else than your actual data, you do not get the desired result :)